# PHP fast way to replace content within string between characters

Tags: php, variables, str-replace

In creating automatic emails certain parts of the email need to be replaced with stored data.

eg. Dear `%first_name% %surname%`, Thanks for attending the `%place_name%`.

This could be done with a string replace for each of them, but there must be a faster method.

Assuming that the variable name is identical to what we want from the system eg. `%first_name%` should be replaced with `$user['first_name']` etc....

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to replace keys between `%`'s with array values:

```
$fields = array('first_name' => 'Tim', 'place_name' => 'Canada');

$string = preg_replace_callback('/%(.+?)%/', function($arr) use($fields)
{
    $key = $arr[1];
    return array_key_exists($key, $fields) ? $fields[$key] : $arr[0];
}, $string);
```

Comment: clever use of closures, which requires the newer versions of PHP

Comment: @Kristian:  PHP 5.3, the version which the anonymous function syntax was introduced, was released 3 years ago.  I wouldn't consider it newer, and I would hope everyone is upgraded to at least that version.

Comment: never underestimate the power of code / version requirements to forcefully slow down upgrades from happening

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
$vars = array(
  'firstname' = 'Bob',
  'surname' = 'Dole',
  'place' = 'Las Vegas',
  // ...
);
extract($vars);
include('my_template.phtml');
```

And in my_template.phtml:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOF
    Dear $firstname $surname,<br>
    Thank you for attending the Viagra and Plantains Expo in $place.
EOF;
?>
```

If you're worried about name collisions while using [`extract()`](http://tw.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), you can always use the `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` option, or one of the other extraction methods.

Or, better yet, don't reinvent the wheel. Just use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/).

See also this question: [PHP template class with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564352/php-template-class-with-variables)

Comment: +1 this is what I do with outputting views, and I recommend it

Comment: @Kristian: Yea, CakePHP and probably a lot of other frameworks/libraries do it this way, albeit usually with additional features like output buffering and, in Cake 2.0, view blocks and view inheritance.